# How to use Django REST Framework to pass data from one app to another, and in different Docker containers?

Tags: python, django, docker, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

My current university assignment consists of us making a cinema website. One of the requirements is that the payment system (I am using Stripe) needs to be a seperate application that runs on a seperate container, and we need to use the Django REST Framework to pass info between them.

My trouble at the moment is that I don't understand how to go through the process of:

- Customer selects all the tickets they want for a viewing
- Pass that information to the Stripe Payment App and redirect the customer to the checkout page
- Process the customers payment, and redirect them back to the main cinema apps index page

I've placed comments in the below code to point out exactly where and how I intend to do this, but I just don't understand how to implement it using REST Framework. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code in the views.py file to process the ticket and showing selection the customer has made is:

```
def make_booking(request, pk=None):
    form = ReservationForm()
    if pk:
        form.fields['showing'].initial = Showing.objects.get(id = pk)
    
# If the submit button is pressed
    if request.method == 'POST':
        .............
        # Code to handle extracting information from the customers form
        .............

                    if (child_quantity > 0):
                        child_booking_data = {
                            'price_data': {
                                'currency': 'gbp',
                                'product_data': {
                                    'name': "Child Ticket",
                                    'description': 'Child ticket for the showing of ' + film.title + ' at ' + film.start_time,
                                },
                                'unit_amount': childTicket.price * 100,
                                },
                            'quantity': child_quantity,
                        }
                    else:
                        child_booking_data = None

                    if (student_quantity > 0):
                        student_booking_data = {
                            'price_data': {
                                'currency': 'gbp',
                                'product_data': {
                                    'name': "Student Ticket",
                                    'description': 'Student ticket for the showing of ' + film.title + ' at ' + film.start_time,
                                },
                                'unit_amount': studentTicket.price * 100,
                                },
                            'quantity': student_quantity,
                        }
                    else:
                        student_booking_data = None

                    if (adult_quantity > 0):
                        adult_booking_data = {
                            'price_data': {
                                'currency': 'gbp',
                                'product_data': {
                                    'name': "Adult Ticket",
                                    'description': 'Adult ticket for the showing of ' + film.title + ' at ' + film.start_time,
                                },
                                'unit_amount': adultTicket.price * 100,
                                },
                            'quantity': adult_quantity,
                        }
                    else:
                        adult_booking_data = None
                    
                    ...............................................
                    # HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO PASS ALL THE ABOVE DATA TO THE STRIPE PAYMENT SYSTEM TO 
                    # APP TO HANDLE MAKING A CHECKOUT
                    ...............................................
                    ...............................................
                    # If the Stripe Payment App processes the checkout successfully, I 
                    # can do the below to actually save the booking


            if int(showing.available_seats) >= total_seats and request.user.account.balance > total_cost:  
                # Save the booking
                booking = form.save(commit=False)
                booking.showing = showing
                booking.save()

                # Update the available seats
                showing.available_seats = int(showing.available_seats) - total_seats
                showing.save()

                return redirect('view_bookings')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'make_booking.html', context)
```

Meanwhile my Stripe code is currently:

```
class CheckoutSessionView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        domain_url = 'http://localhost:8000/'
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

        total_cost = request.data.get('total_cost')
        try:
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            client_reference_id=request.user.id if request.user.is_authenticated else None,
            success_url=domain_url + 'paymentConfirm?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url=domain_url,
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            mode='payment',
            line_items=[ # Needs to be adjusted to take what tickets were selected, and how many
                child_booking_data,
                student_booking_data,
                adult_booking_data,
            ]
        )

            return Response({'session_id': checkout_session.id, 'url': checkout_session.url}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```